# How to disable a link based on a variable value in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have piece of code in HTML.
I need to open a pop up based on a value in the variable?
if variable value is true then it should be clickable but, in case of false it should not perform any action. Below is the code i am using.
So "about" is a variable which is either true or false.
**project.about = true/false**

```
   <a title="Refresh Project"
   ng-click="refreshProjectPopUp(project)"
   <span class="refresh-icon rightSpace"></span>
   </a>
```

I am not able to think how to  add this condition here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `<a>` tag is missing the closing `>`. It's also missing the `href` attribute, which means it won't link anywhere and is effectively already disabled.

Comment: You are using angularjs too? add the tag for it here as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<a title="Refresh Project"
   <a *ngIf="project.about==true"
   ng-click="refreshProjectPopUp(project)"
   </a>
   <span class="refresh-icon rightSpace"></span>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator to bind the function. When the value is true the function will be called and if the value is false then nothing will happen.

Try to change the value of the `project.about` from true to false.

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok123/ufcob75p/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

 <a title="Refresh Project" ng-click=" project.about ? refreshProjectPopUp(project) : ''">
    <span class="refresh-icon rightSpace">link</span>
 </a>
   
<br>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.project = {};
    $scope.project.about  = true;
    $scope.refreshProjectPopUp = function() {
        alert('Link is clicked');
    };
});
</script>

</body>
```